# find min and max index in numpy array column for a certain value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array which looks like this:

```
['0.0002126159536893578' '0']
['0.000489237210943365' '0']
 ...
['6.998729658062154e-05' '3']
['7.956089498242174e-07' '3']
['9.178127570732645e-06' '3']]
```

Its sorted first by the second column and then by the first column, now i need to get the index of the first and the last occurance of each value in the second column so i can extract the value of the first column (if there is an easier method that would be great =D)

Comment: Consider using Pandas dataframe, and `groupby`. Also, your data seems to be string type, you may need to convert it to float.

Comment: I used the numpy_indexed package https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP
which has a group by alternative for numpy, but the data is already grouped, i just want to know how i can get the indexes, is this possible with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is already sorted by second columns, you can try:

```
uniques, idx = np.unique(arr[:,1], return_index=True)
```

Then `idx` contains the first occurences for each unique value in `uniques`.